# How do I concatenate a query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query that gives an error when trying to concatenate an integer with the query.

```
    $order_id = Order::find($id);
    $orderid = $order_id['order_id'];

    $shipping_address = DB::table('shipping_addresses')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
    $order_products =  DB::select('SELECT * FROM orders JOIN order_products ON orders.id = order_products.order_id WHERE order_id ='.$orderid );
```

How do I concatenate the `$orderid` ? Thanks

Comment: My be it would be `$orderid = $order_id->order_id;`

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @JohnathanBarrett "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: SELECT * FROM orders JOIN order_products ON orders.id = order_products.order_id WHERE order_id =) ◀" but I have solved it using the Vincent's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using Stackoverflow, you should learn how to debug (easy) code.

This line :

```
$order_id = Order::find($id);
```

If you debug $order_id, you will see it's an Eloquent Model, not a integer. The `find()` method returns the Model, not only the ID.

Then, why are you querying from the ID to collect the ID ?!

Just use :

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM orders 
     JOIN order_products ON orders.id = order_products.order_id 
     WHERE order_id ='.$id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the `$orderid` to query as

```
$order_products =  DB::select('SELECT * FROM orders JOIN order_products ON orders.id = order_products.order_id WHERE order_id ='".$orderid."' );
```